# display issues with ubuntu 16.04LTS -AMD processor and AMD graphic Card

Tags: 64-bit, amd-graphics

I am facing issues with the my laptop display ever since i installed Ubuntu 16.04.

Whenever i start my system i can observe my laptop being fully functional but nothing is being displayed on the screen it shows only black screen,
then i have to force shutdown my system ,start it again.
This happens regularly(5 out of 10 times).